# VPN service with proxy forwarding

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn

I have 2 computers that are both inside NAT, where I do not want (preferable) to do port forwarding (or related things), however want to unite them with VPN to get access to private network. Let's call one computer "working station" and another "PLC forwarder". So, "working station" (client) connects to the "PLC forwarder" and can access it's private LAN network. My main purpose is to provide access to remote PLC controller that is on one LAN with "PLC forwarder". There is a good [link](http://www.plcs.net/downloads/index.php?action=downloadfile&filename=How%20to%20setup%20Teamviewer%20VPN.pdf&directory=Misc&) that shows what I want to achive. It requires TeamViewer software that is quite expensive. It [TeamViewer] works fine as it moves traffic through their servers and I do not have a need to do router settings. And my questions are:

1) Do you know some service (for money is fine, unless too much) that can do same things - computer to computer VPN connection with proxying (thus I do not thoughts about static IP's or port forwarding - just some computer ID). I am sorry for asking this, as I googled proxy vpn or cloud vpn and got answers that are far distant from what I need.

2) I can set up any server software (ex. linux) on "PLC forwarder" as it's final aim to provide connection to PLC. May be you know some packets that are close to my needs. If yes, just name is fine.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't configure a port forwarding, you need either NAT hole punching, which is unreliable, or relaying the traffic through some external server, which slows down communication and costs money for somebody.

If you want to go for the relaying traffic through an external server, I can think of two services, which will relay traffic for free. That is gogo6 and SixXS, using those requires the two endpoints to support IPv6 but you don't need IPv6 support on the path between them.

If you are relying on software without IPv6 support, you can instead rent a VPS and configure your own VPN server there. There are lots of cheap VPS providers.

Comment: If I will try to rent VPS and set up VPN here. Is it possible to `push` "PLC forwarder"s LAN to this VPN? Because I do not need access to the PLC forwarder" itself. Only to it's lan. There is an option, however, to build VPN virst to get 2 PCs in one network and then make another VPN over it to access LAN. I want remote computer to feel like inside my network. How to do this without 2 VPN? Thanks!

Comment: @Tigran that's a bit more work, but it is definitely possible. You just need to create a few static routes telling the involved computers, which way to route traffic. You could for example have four hops on the path, where the first and the last was a local Ethernet connection, and the middle two is VPN connection between each site and the VPS. In each end of the VPN connection you need to create such static routes on the machine where the VPN connection is terminated as well on the gateway (you did not tell us if those two are the same machine).